"Sound Info" geometry attribute to shader
I have a Sound Info geometry node and I want to take the (beat or loudness) value and plug into a Noise texture node (in the Shader tab).
using the artribute shader node, how do I set this up?


I do not know what a "Sound Info" node is as it seems to be custom made, but it seems to output float values.
So in Geometry Nodes you can plug the output of the Sound Info node into a Store Named Attribute node, set it to Float and Point. Enter a name in the Name field like "sound" and use that exact name in the Attribute node in the Shader Editor.
Now the only problem is that attributes are stored in the point or vertex domain. If you have a simple plane with four corner vertices as it seems in your screenshot, only these four vertices hold any information for the shader. So in order to get more data all over the face, you should subdivide it in Geometry Nodes. Important: the subdivided needs to be the output of the Geometry Nodes, otherwise the information will not be transferred to the mesh in the shader.
Here an example setup (I've used a Random Value node as source for the attribute because I have no Sound Info):


this answers the question perfectly! thank you for the explaination and example!

@CpToye_00 You're welcome. Some off-topic question from me here: this sound info node looks like something I could use. I tested the free lite version but with recent Blender versions it throws an error and the node has no outputs. With which version are you using it? (Sorry, this has nothing to do with the answer but I don't know how to open a chat here.)
